# How to automatically remove Active Admin form inputs with Pundit permitted attributes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin, pundit

I have a Rails 4 app using Active Admin 1.0.0.pre1 in conjunction with pundit 0.3.0 for authorization which has worked flawlessly thus far, but I'm having trouble figuring out a good way automatically customize forms based on a user's role.

Given these models:

```
ActiveAdmin.register AdminUser do
  permit_params do
    Pundit.policy(current_admin_user, resource).permitted_attributes
  end

  form do |f|
    f.inputs "Admin Details" do
      f.input :role, as: :select, collection: [:manager, :admin]
      f.input :email, as: :email
      f.input :password
      f.input :password_confirmation
    end
    f.actions
  end
end

class AdminUserPolicy < ApplicationPolicy
  def permitted_attributes
    attributes = [:email, :password, :password_confirmation]
    attributes += [:role] if user.has_role? :super_admin
    attributes
  end
end
```

I'd like for the `role` input to be automatically removed from the form.

One option would be something along the lines of:

```
  permitted_attributes = Pundit.policy(current_admin_user, resource).permitted_attributes

  form do |f|
    f.inputs "Admin Details" do
      f.input :role if permitted_attributes.include? :role
      f.input :email
      f.input :password
      f.input :password_confirmation
    end
    f.actions
  end
```

but, that approach requires the developer to remember which attributes should be checked, seems prone to forgetfulness and isn't exactly DRY.  Perhaps, I am going about this the wrong way?  All suggestions welcome.

Comment: I am 95% sure, the answer hides somewhere along the `main_content` method here: https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/master/lib/active_admin/views/pages/form.rb. I don't have an open project with AA right now to test it out, but you can override that class and try manually exclude the `:role` input from buider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intercepting ActiveAdminForm by prepending a module that overrides `input` with a check against the Pundit policy seems to work well.  Here is the implementation I went with:

```
# /lib/active_admin/permitted_active_admin_form.rb
module PermittedActiveAdminForm
  def permitted_attributes
    policy = Pundit.policy(current_admin_user, resource)
    policy.respond_to?(:permitted_attributes) ? policy.permitted_attributes : []
  end

  def input(*args)
    super(*args) if permitted_attributes.include? args[0]
  end
end


# /config/initializers/active_admin.rb
module ActiveAdmin
  module Views
    class ActiveAdminForm < FormtasticProxy
      prepend PermittedActiveAdminForm
    end
  end
end

# /app/admin/admin_user.rb
ActiveAdmin.register AdminUser do
  permit_params do
    resource ||= AdminUser
    Pundit.policy(current_admin_user, resource).permitted_attributes
  end

  form do |f|
    f.inputs "Admin Details" do
      f.input :role, as: :select, collection: [:manager, :admin]
      f.input :email, as: :email
      f.input :password
      f.input :password_confirmation
    end
    f.actions
  end
end
```

Thanks to Andrey Deineko for starting me down the right path.

Comment: Do note that there could be issues from the active admin login form because it runs outside of the ActiveAdmin::BaseController codebase. It might work in this case but if you use methods like `active_admin_authorization` to get the authorization adapter and operate on it, it will work on all forms once logged in, but not during log out, worst, it will crash the login view.

Answer (score 0):

I know pundit, not active_admin. With that in mind, using the code you provided, I'll just throw an idea out there.

```
whitelist = Pundit.policy(current_admin_user, resource).permitted_attributes
fields    = %i( role email password password_confirmation )

form do |f|
  f.inputs "Admin Details" do
    (fields & whitelist).each do |field|
      f.input field
    end
  end
  f.actions
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!  The problem here is that the arguments to `f.input` vary depending on the field so I will need call each one explicitly with the correct args.  I have updated my example to better reflect that.  In the same vain, I considered building a hash where the the field represents the key with the value being the options.  Then I could have a helper method loop over the hash to make the correct calls, but I was hoping for a tighter integration.